# Get text from Gtk3 TextView/TextBuffer with formatting tags included in Python

Tags: python, formatting, gtk3

I'm working on a Python 3 project that uses the Gtk3 TextView/TextBuffer to get a user's input, and I've got it working to where I can have the user typing in rich text and able to format it as Bold/Italic/Underline/Combination of these.

However, I'm stuck on trying to figure out how to get the text from the TextBuffer with those flags included so I can use the formatting flags to convert the text to properly formatted HTML when I need to.

Calling `textbuffer.get_text(start, end, True)` simply returns the text without any flags.

Here's [the code](http://pastebin.com/nacFiLKZ) and [the `editor.glade` file](http://pastebin.com/NM3kH5dX). Save them both in the same directory.

How can I get the text with the flags included? Or, alternatively, is there a way I can get the user's input formatted as HTML automatically in another variable automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not very easy. [Here](https://github.com/ptomato/osxcart/blob/master/osxcart/rtf-serialize.c) is a link to some code that I once wrote to do the same thing for RTF output. You can probably adapt it to produce HTML output. If you manage to do so, I'd possibly integrate it into that library's successor.

Alternatively, if you prefer text processing to the above, you can export the rich text in GtkTextBuffer's internal serialization format and convert it to HTML yourself later:

```
format = textbuffer.register_serialize_tagset('my-tagset')
exported = textbuffer.serialize(textbuffer, format, start, end)
```

Comment: Thanks! Your code isn't a *whole* lot of help to me, since I'm using Python and know about a pea-sized amount of C, but your `textbuffer.serialize()` suggestion was stupendous. I've done XML parsing before, so that was perfect!